# How to build webpack project with index.html on the build folder and all dependencies in another folder?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I need to build my webpack project putting the index.html inside build folder and all other files/dependencies in a child folder, let´s say something like this:

```
/build
  index.html
  /includes
    main.4577834a.chunk.css
    main.4577834a.chunk.css.br
    main.4577834a.chunk.js
    ...
```

Does anybody know how to config webpack.prod.js to do that?

Comment: how is your index.html is generated? are you running your application in react/angular/view? Are you using html-webpack-loader?

Comment: @RazRonen my index.html is generated using the index.html template, it works the way it is, but I need to separate everything from index.html folder, my application is react, and no, I am not using html-web-pack-loader.